# Modify Global ArrayList from Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

What I am trying to do is to modify global ArrayList inside a thread and have this modified ArrayList outside of my Thread.

This is my code, it works but when I read my ArrayList from outside, it has a correct size but all elements in this ArrayList are the last one added, I mean if last element has pollingCode,pollingType,polling Value = 0, all elements in the array have the same values.

Does anybody know why this happens?

```
public abstract class OverlayView extends RelativeLayout {

protected ArrayList<InputEvent> eventList       = new ArrayList<InputEvent>();

public void StartEventMonitor() {
        Thread b = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {

                    InputEvent ie= new InputEvent();
                    while (m_bMonitorOn) {
                        for (InputDevice idev:events.m_Devs) {
                            // Open more devices to see their messages

                            int pollingEvent = idev.getPollingEvent();

                                int pollingType=idev.getSuccessfulPollingType();
                                int pollingCode=idev.getSuccessfulPollingCode();
                                int pollingValue=idev.getSuccessfulPollingValue();

                                final String line =/* idev.getName()+
                                        ": " +*/ idev.getSuccessfulPollingType()+
                                        " " + idev.getSuccessfulPollingCode() + 
                                        " " + idev.getSuccessfulPollingValue() +
                                        "\n";
                                Log.d(LT, "Event:"+line);

                                ie.setCode(pollingCode);
                                ie.setType(pollingType);
                                ie.setValue(pollingValue);
                                eventList.add(ie);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            b.start();    
   }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just an FYI this has nothing to do with multithreading.

You are re-using the same InputEvent object.  So what you invoke `setCode` you are invoking the setCode method of the same InputEvent.  The adding simply will add the same IE instance every time.

For instance, try (assuming the list size > 1)

```
if(eventList.get(0) == eventList.get(1)){
   //re using the same object
}
```

You should move the creation assignment of InputEvent inside the for loop.

Comment: thanks man. the problem is solved now ;) I guess this is my mistake because I always try to avoid new object creations if I dont need to... Usually when I add elements into an arrayList I normally use the same object just changing values with setters

Comment: @CarlosMoreradeLaChica For whatever it's worth - Object creation in its general form is not expensive and you shouldn't worry about it.  There are some like SimpleDateFormat and others that are reported to be expensive.  Josh Bloch noted that 20% of CPU time is spent on 80% of your code.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried creating a new InputEvent in the loop. You only have one ie that you add the list and you just update the values on that `InputEvent`:

```
InputEvent ie= new InputEvent();
while (m_bMonitorOn) {
    ie= new InputEvent();
 ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Without studying your code in all details: You list isn't thread-safe. I recommend you use something like an [ArrayBlockingQueue](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html) to share the events between your threads. That will remove major issues and in any case be the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 mistakes:

First, change:

```
protected ArrayList<InputEvent> eventList = new ArrayList<InputEvent>();
```

to

```
protected final List<InputEvent> eventList = 
    Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<InputEvent>());
```

This will make adding and removing item from List thread safe. Now we need to fix problem with adding item. For every event you need new InputEvent instance. So change your loop following way:

```
public void run() {
    while (m_bMonitorOn) {
        for (InputDevice idev:events.m_Devs) {
            InputEvent ie= new InputEvent();
               ...
            eventList.add(ie);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I have a doubt, which is exactly the difference between using

protected ArrayList<InputEvent> eventList = new ArrayList<InputEvent>();

protected final List<InputEvent> eventList = 
    Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<InputEvent>());

I didnt understand why this will make adding and removing item from List thread safe. 

Thanks again

Comment: [final is a way of thread safe publication](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_final.shtml)